# How to deal with inconsistencies after doing manipulation?

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

Given a problem as follows.

> Find the range of
> $$
> f(x)=\frac{4x}{\sqrt{(25+x^2)(1+x^2)}}
> $$
> for any real $x$.

#### My Attempt

\begin{gather}
y=\frac{4x}{\sqrt{(25+x^2)(1+x^2)}}\\
\sqrt{(25+x^2)(1+x^2)}=\frac{4x}{y}\\
x^4+26x^2+25 = \frac{16}{y^2}x^2\\
x^4+(26-\frac{16}{y^2})x^2+25=0
\end{gather}

As $y$ is defined for any real $x$ then $x^2$ must be non-negative real numbers.

The constraints are
\begin{gather}
D\geq 0 \quad\text{and}\quad -\frac{b}{a} \geq 0 \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{c}{a} \geq 0
\end{gather}

As you can see, the third constraint has been satisfied so only the first two constraints will be considered as follows.

First constraint:
\begin{gather}
(26-\frac{16}{y^2})^2 - 4\times 1\times 25 \geq 0\\
\frac{64(y-1)(y+1)(3y-2)(3y+2)}{y^4}\geq 0
\end{gather}

The solution is $(-\infty,-1]\cup[-2/3,0)\cup(0,2/3]\cup[1,\infty)$.

Second constraint:
\begin{gather}
-\frac{26-\frac{16}{y^2}}{1} \geq 0\\
26-\frac{16}{y^2} \leq 0 \\
\frac{(y\sqrt{26}-4)(y\sqrt{26}+4)}{y^2} \leq 0
\end{gather}

The solution is $[-4/\sqrt{26},0)\cup(0,4/\sqrt{26}]$.

By intersecting the above solutions, the range of $f(x)$ is $[-2/3,0)\cup(0,2/3]$.

### Question

If we consider the $f(x)$, it will be zero if $x=0$. However the previously calculated range says it never reach zero.  How to avoid this contradictory result?

Comment: Since $f(0) = 0$, you should add $0$ to your range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $x = 0$, we have $f(x) = 0$ from the definition of $x$, which you would write as $y = 0$.

In the second line of your "attempt", you divide by $y$, but fail to note that this is only valid (as are all subsequent steps) if $y \ne 0$ (hence $x \ne 0$).

So the answer is: keep track of your domains, especially when dividing by anything or when squaring (or applying other non-injective functions) both sides of an equality.